# Is there a plugin like mongoosastic to use with loopback?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, full-text-search, loopback, mongoosastic

I want to use `elasticsearch` to provide full-text search for my application, After googled i have decided to use `mongoosastic`, but that plugin is with `express`. So is there an equivalent plugin to use it with `loopback`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a loopback connector for elasticsearch take a look at the following. https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-connector-elastic-search

More info related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30238659/1849366) can be found in this answer.